# Fit large wav file to CD

Tags: ubuntu-mate, cd, audio-recording

I am trying to get a 3 hour song onto a CD.

```
ffmpeg -i Flying.mp3 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 6000 my_output_file.wav
```

I shrunk it to a 6000 sampling rate to reduce the size.

File size is 250 Mb, so it should fit?

I am using Xfburn.

Any other ideas?

Comment: A CD is either 640MB or 720MB so it should fit.

Comment: k3b said it was 100 minutes too long. Looking now to shorten it. @Terrance

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because it is uncompressing it to a .WAV format since really that is what CD Audio is.  CDs really can only hold up to 74 minutes of audio.

Comment: I see. @Terrance

Comment: Depending on the CD Player, a lot of the newer ones can actually play .MP3 files so you wouldn't have to worry about that.  I have some MP3 files that are up to 8 hours long and can fit on a data cd that can be played in my car stereo, because it has the ability to play them.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot my car player played mp3s. I got over 4 hrs on a RW-CD. @Terrance

Answer (score -1):

I found out a CD holds 80 minutes of audio.

I was trying to put 180 minutes on the CD.

I used Audacity to shrink the mp3 file.